# Deleting products via PHPmyAdmin

Tags: magento-1.9, database, delete

Would there be any adverse effect deleting products via PHPMyAdmin with Magento 1.9?

I have reached the limit of my MYSQL Database with my hosting company however, I am unable to delete old products from within Magento or Linnworks as I get an access denied.  My hosting company advised I could delete via PHPMyAdmin however I am unsure if doing this would have serious consequences on any linked data within Magento database.  In the meantime my website is in an error state and my customers cannot view it's contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are receiving an "Access Denied" error in Magento, you will most likely not be able to connect via phpMyAdmin (assuming you are using the same credentials that Magento uses). I'd be curious to find out how you reached a limit with the MySQL database, this doesn't sound like something a normal hosting contract works.

**MAKE SURE TO BACKUP YOUR DATABASE BEFORE ATTEMPTING ANYTHING**

You can easily delete products from Magento's database by running a query similar to

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `sku` IN ('SKU', 'OtherSKU', ... ,'SKU N');
```

where each SKU is relating to a product SKU within the admin panel.

With how Magento's database is designed, this query will cascade and remove the product from all the associated tables, barring custom functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it's the way the hosting company want me to upgrade to another server but it won't take my data with it and as I run an online shop this is totally unacceptable.  How do I run this query.... ?  Is it with Magento or PHPMyAdmin ?  I would be looking for stock with level 0 to remove.  I have a bit of knowledge of PHP MyAdmin but it's definitely not my second language so would need a bit of hand holding on this if you wouldn't mind

Comment: @kate You can run it from phpMyAdmin as a MySQL query against your Magento database